# Checkstyle suppressions: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: regex, checkstyle

I'm using checkstyle on the commandline. Not in Maven or ANT.

I've defined a `suppressions.xml` file and referenced it from my `-c CheckstyleConfig.xml`.

Checkstyle runs (no parsing errors), but it isn't suppressing anything.

I'm trying to make Checkstyle ignore `.class` files. Here is the content of my `suppression.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
"-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
"http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
<suppressions>
 <suppress checks="." files="(.*\.class)"/>
</suppressions>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Checkstyle is still processing `.class` files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Checkstyle works on whatever you feed it. A default eclipse-cs installation will only feed it Java files and property files, but since you're running from the command line, you'll have to exclude the `.class` files from checking or suppress the warnings.

It is better to exclude the `.class` files from checking (so that Checkstyle never sees them), because it will save you time.

But if you want to suppress the warnings, you can do that, too. The `files` regex in a *suppressions.xml* is greedy, so `.*` already covers the whole file name, and the pattern in your example never matches. Try this syntax (suppressing all `.class` files):

```
<suppressions>
    <suppress checks=".*" files="\.class$" />
</suppressions>
```

Comment: Btw, using `.` or `.*` in the `checks` argument does not matter. Both variants match all checks, just in different ways.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this issue.  This issue was related to a project at a previous job.  That job SUUUUUUUUUUUCKED (Lockheed Martin).  If i remember, the way I got around the problem was, I wrapped made a PERL script to send only java files to CS.

Comment: Yeah, in fact Checkstyle checks whatever you give it. So if you gave it class files, you chose the right solution with your script. Not feeding the wrong files to CS is better than having CS suppress the warnings. I'll adjust my answer - didn't so far cuz I thought the question was dead. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Checkstyle does not work on class files, it cannot parse them. Checkstyle works on Java source code, which are files that end with ".java".

So, the problem is your regular expression to suppress errors. The suppression should be:

```
<suppress checks="." files="(.*\.java)"/>
```

Comment: The checks should also be a regular expression